# Rational number generator (Python)

Tags: python

1. Why is it getting rid of the [1,3],[3,2] entry and replacing it with [2,3],[3,1]?
2. Note, [2,3],[3,1] is the correct branch, but it should not override the previous entry, it should be appended to it.

   ```
   def rational():
       treecount = 0
       tree = [[[1,1]]]
       left=[0,0]
       right=[0,0]
       while(True):
           treecount+=1
           tree.append([])
           left=[0,0]
           right=[0,0]
           for z in range(len(tree[treecount-1])):
               left[0] = tree[treecount-1][z][0]
               right[0] = tree[treecount-1][z][0] + tree[treecount-1][z][1]
               left[1] = tree[treecount-1][z][1] + tree[treecount-1][z][0]
               right[1] = tree[treecount-1][z][1]
               tree[treecount].append(left)
               tree[treecount].append(right)
               yield( tree)
   ```

Output looks like this:

```
[[[1, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]]] [[[1, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 3], [3, 2]]] [[[1, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1]]]
```

Comment: [[[1, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]]]  /////////////////
                                                                 [[[1, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[1, 3], [3, 2]]]/////////////////////
                                                                 [[[1, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 3], [3, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1]]]     //////////////////                                                                                                                                   output looks like this

Comment: you can [edit] your post to add more information if needed, just look to the bottom right of the question and find the link that says `edit`

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Stuart: It looks like an attempt to generate the Calkin-Wilf tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin–Wilf_tree

Comment: @MarkDickinson if that's the case, maybe user3241663 should check out [the `fractions` module](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html) for a better way of representing the rational values and use those as node values rather than trying to do this all in lists. Python isn't LISP, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a fundamental aspect of Python's object model, namely that Python never makes copies of objects implicitly.

In your code, you create two new lists `left` and `right` just before entering the `for` loop.  You then repeatedly modify those two lists and append them to your tree so far.  That's fine, except that all you're doing is appending references to the *same* two lists repeatedly.

Here's a simpler example of this phenomenon. We'll create a list `left` and append it to another list `outer`:

```
>>> outer = []
>>> left = [1, 3]
>>> outer.append(left)
>>> outer
[[1, 3]]
```

So far so good: everything's behaving as expected.  But now let's modify `left` and append it to `outer` again:

```
>>> left[0] = 4
>>> outer.append(left)
>>> outer
[[4, 3], [4, 3]]
```

Notice how the first entry of `outer` has changed?  That's because `outer` doesn't contain two independent lists at this point:  instead, it contains two references to the *same* list.  And that's what's happening in your code above.

It's straightforward to fix:  create `left` and `right` afresh on every iteration of the `for` loop:

```
for z in range(len(tree[treecount-1])):
    left=[0, 0]
    right=[0, 0]
    left[0] = tree[treecount-1][z][0]
    right[0] = tree[treecount-1][z][0] + tree[treecount-1][z][1]
    left[1] = tree[treecount-1][z][1] + tree[treecount-1][z][0]
    <and so on>
```

Alternatively, you can make copies of `left` and `right` before appending them:

```
tree[treecount].append(list(left))
tree[treecount].append(list(right))
```

Incidentally, you can simplify your code substantially if you make better use of some of Python's idioms.  First, iterating over `range(len(something))` is often unnecessary, especially when you're going to use the values directly as indices.  Iterate directly over the list instead.  Second, you can unpack the `tree[treecount-1]` value directly in the `for` statement.  Then you can use negative indices to index from the end of the list, saving you the need to maintain `treecount`.  With those first-pass changes, your code looks like this:

```
def rational():
    tree = [[[1,1]]]
    while True:
        tree.append([])
        for a, b in tree[-2]:
            left = [a, b + a]
            right = [a + b, b]
            tree[-1].extend([left, right])
            yield tree
```

There's still room for improvement, but this is already much more readable than the original code.

Comment: Thank you! Very well explained and a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need the tree, but simply want to iterate over positive rationals, you can use this generator.  Output is in the same order as a breadth-first traversal of the Calkin-Wilf tree, but without the cost of an ever-growing queue.

```
from fractions import Fraction
def Calkin_Wilf():
   x = Fraction(1, 1)
   yield x
   while True:
      x = Fraction(1, 2*Fraction(int(x))-x+1)
      yield x
```

Use the generator to create an iterator, then iterate with next(), e.g.:

```
rational = Calkin_Wilf()
for _ in range(100):
   print(next(rational))
```